# 18.04 LTS unstable performance [very slow startup + sudden desktop freezing]

Tags: 18.04

Since the upgrade from 16.04LTS to 18.04LTS I am struggling with an unstable machine.

*It takes ages to start (so slow I can compare it to old windows)
*It randomly freezes to the point where I can only force shut it down and have to restart, obviously losing the work that wasn't saved. Interestigly the mouse work but all the rest of the desktop gets unresponsive completely.

Some details from Hardinfo:

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Memory  16384MB (3208MB used)
Machine Type    Desktop
Operating System    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Kernel  Linux 4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Version #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018
C Library   GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27

I'd like to ask some help to understand what is the matter? Any log that could relatively easily show why it takes so long to start and why it crashes so many times a day?

Comment: Seem to have a similar problem. You running a graphics card?

Comment: @BobserLuck indeed I have  an nvidia graphics card.

Comment: I will try to get some evidence but I am starting to see a correlation with google chrome ie it seems whenever the OS freezes I am using chrome. Will revert to firefox and advise

Comment: I've used the machine for a few days on Firefox and the incidence of frozen desktop greatly reduced. Following the graphic card hint @BobserLuck I have now disabled the _use hardware acceleration when available_ functionality on Chrome because I suspect that this setting  could be at the root of this issue.

Comment: No _joy_ after less than one hour using Chrome with disabled  hardware acceleration when available functionality on the machine froze again.

Comment: Any proprietary drivers?  I had terrible stability issues (on 16.04) because I was running the nVidia driver. Swapping to Nouveau fixed things.

Comment: I have been seeing hangs on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS also. I found that I can get it unfrozen by hitting ctrl-alt-delete, which brings up the logout popup, and if I just click on `cancel`, it all starts working again.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you see the baloo-file process running - it is a search service that is indexing your files. In my case I had the same symptoms until after this search indexer completed. This should explain your improved experience over time as well.